# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ERROR

Tags: php, http-headers

I just thought it was white space, but after further research I think it might be a problem similar to this:

> Look for any statements that could send output to the user before this header statement. If you find one or more, change your code to move the header statement before them. Complex conditional statements may complicate the issue, but they may also help solve the problem. Consider a conditional expression at the top of the PHP script that determines the header value as early as possible and sets it there.

I'm guessing the include header is causing the problem along with the header(), but I'm not sure how to rearrange the code to get rid of this error.

I moved the include header below the headers() and I'm not getting the errors. However, the header file includes the menu options for each location so as I've moved the include header below the headers() the menu options are not changing.

How do I remove the error?

```
<?php
    $username = "";

    include_once 'header.php';

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
        $username = sanitizeString($_POST['username']);

    if ($username != 'admin')
    {
        header("Location:summary.php");
    }
    elseif($username == 'admin')
    {
        header("Location:admin.php");
    }
    elseif($username == '')
    {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
    else
        // ... rest of the code
```

Comment: Assuming that there are no spaces before the <? in the file you listed, there's some output occurring in the header.php file, intended or not.  If header.php is actually supposed to produce some output, then you should place the login conditional before you include header.php, otherwise you'll just need to go in and eliminate any output created in the header.php file.  Most likely culprits, in my experience, is extra whitespace either before the opening <? tag or after the closing ?> tag.  For certain if you don't see any characters before the error, you're looking for whitespace.

Comment: ~~~~~~~~~~ file ENCODING should not be `UTF-8`, but `UTF-8 (Without BOM)`~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The long-term answer is that all output from your PHP scripts should be buffered in variables. This includes headers and body output. Then at the end of your scripts do any output you need.

The very quick fix for your problem will be to add

```
ob_start();
```

as the very first thing in your script, if you only need it in this one script. If you need it in all your scripts add it as the very first thing in your header.php file.

This turns on PHP's output buffering feature. In PHP when you output something (do an echo or print) it has to send the HTTP headers at that time. If you turn on output buffering you can output in the script but PHP doesn't have to send the headers until the buffer is flushed. If you turn it on and don't turn it off PHP will automatically flush everything in the buffer after the script finishes running. There really is no harm in just turning it on in almost all cases and could give you a small performance increase under some configurations.

If you have access to change your php.ini configuration file you can find and change or add the following

```
output_buffering = On
```

This will turn output buffering out without the need to call ob_start().

To find out more about output buffering check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Is this good practise? I mean since `PHP` is throwing an error does that mean there could be a better way of doing it.

Comment: @James111, this is often an issue when trying to add tests to a legacy application. Often the application was not designed to be run from the command line. Ideally you refactor the application to support run like this. Ideally if you are going to refactor it's best to have tests to help know if anything was broken. I would chose adding tests first and using things like the above solution as a bridge to getting both.

Answer (score 9):

Check something with `echo`, `print()` or `printr()` in the include file, `header.php`.

It might be that this is the problem OR if any MVC file, then check the number of spaces after `?>`. This could also make a problem.

Answer (score 6):

There are some problems with your `header()` calls, one of which might be causing problems

- You should put an `exit()` after each of the `header("Location:` calls otherwise code execution will continue
- You should have a space after the `:` so it reads `"Location: http://foo"`
- It's not valid to use a relative URL in a `Location` header, you should form an absolute URL like `http://www.mysite.com/some/path.php`

Comment: But my all the relative urls in `header()` are working except one.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to send headers information after outputing content.

If you want to do this, look for [output buffering.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Therefore, look to use `ob_start();`