# To fetch another database content in my wp site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have php site and a wordpress site. I want to connect the php site db in my wordpress site.

I have tried like this

```
define('DB_NAME', 'mydbname');
define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_HOST', 'my-host');
$second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$your_query = "SELECT * FROM DOCTORS";
$results = $second_db->get_results($your_query);
print_r($results);
```

Array ( ) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

I need the table data display in my theme. How can it be possible ? Please help me.

Comment: where you have defined db details and on which page your are using them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707693/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-error  hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without define variables. 
or change your variable names

Try this

```
define('DB_NAME_1', 'mydbname');
define('DB_USER_1', 'myusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD_1', 'mypassword');
define('DB_HOST_1', 'my-host');
$second_db = new wpdb(DB_USER_1, DB_PASSWORD_1, DB_NAME_1, DB_HOST_1);
$your_query = "SELECT * FROM DOCTORS";
$results = $second_db->get_results($your_query);
print_r($results);
```

OR Try with this

```
$second_db = new wpdb('myusername', 'mypassword', 'mydbname', 'my-host');
$your_query = "SELECT * FROM DOCTORS";
$results = $second_db->get_results($your_query);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: how to print the data as an array ?

Comment: print_r($results); it's print result array. if you want to print data then use foreach loop as 
foreach ( $results as $fivesdraft ) 
{
 echo $fivesdraft->column_name;
}