# SQL pulling first character of each column

Tags: php, sql

So I've got a dropdown that has a list of customers that you can select from.  It uses a function (that someone else built) which works fine when there are 2 or more customers but dies when there it only one.  When there's one customer, each item in the `dropdown` is the first character of each `column` for that one customer.

Here is the *function*:

```
function getCustomerBy($column = "",$value = "")
        {
            global $conn;
            if ($value == '')
                {
            return(null);
                }
            $sel = "SELECT 
            customers.*,
            customerStatus.code customerStatus
            FROM customers,
            customerStatus      
            WHERE customer_id
            and  customerStatus.id = customers.customerStatus_id and   ". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$column) ."='". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value) ."'";
            //      error_log($sel);
            $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);
            $check = mysqli_num_rows($run);

            if ($check ==1)
            {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
                    return($row);
            }
            elseif($check >1)
            {
                    $rows = array();
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
            {
                    $rows[] = $row;
            }
                    return($rows);
            }
            else
            {
                    return(null);
            }
    }
```

I'm fairly certain that it's the (`$check == 1`) stuff but I can't work out the best way to re-do all of that to make it work without causing other errors (specifically "cannot modify header")

This is what's called up on the page with the `dropdown`:

```
 $customers = getCustomerBy('users_user_id',$user['user_id']);
```

Also, here is the code for the `dropdown`:

```
 <?
      foreach ($customers as $customer)
      {
      $selected = '';
      if (isset($gig['customers_customer_id']) && $customer['customer_id'] == $gig['customers_customer_id'])
 {
      $selected = ' selected ';
 }
 echo "\t<option value=\"".$customer['customer_id']."\"      $selected>".$customer['customer_company_name']."</option>";
 }
 ?>
```

[image: Broken dropdown]

Comment: *"(specifically "cannot modify header")"* - Fix that and see where your code goes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: That error only happened when I hacked up the code above, and probably badly, which is why I'm hoping someone might be able to help steer me in the right direction :)

Comment: Why not just get rid of the `if $check == 1` block altogether and treat both cases the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that builds the dropdown is expecting an array of arrays, but instead when it's a single row you're passing it an array of strings. Treat both cases (`$check > 0`) the same.

```
function getCustomerBy($column = "",$value = "")
    {
        global $conn;
        if ($value == '')
            {
        return(null);
            }
        $sel = "SELECT 
        customers.*,
        customerStatus.code customerStatus
        FROM customers,
        customerStatus      
        WHERE customer_id
        and  customerStatus.id = customers.customerStatus_id and   ". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$column) ."='". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$value) ."'";
        //      error_log($sel);
        $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);
        $check = mysqli_num_rows($run);

        if($check > 0)
        {
                $rows = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
        {
                $rows[] = $row;
        }
                return($rows);
        }
        else
        {
                return(null);
        }
}
```

I assume there's copy/paste errors in your query because it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the returning array is used by the rest of your code but you can try the following:

Change:

```
if ($check ==1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
    return($row);
}
```

To this:

```
if ($check == 1) {
    $rows = array();
    $rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);
    return($rows);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That throws the header error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/chrisstolz/public_html/managegigs.com/client/layouts/layout_head.php:8) in /home/chrisstolz/public_html/managegigs.com/client/includes/functions.php on line 33

  Line 8 is:    <?php echo "<title>".$title." | ManageGigs</title>"; ?>

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707693/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-error