# php sessionid works on desktop with refresh, not on mobile, gives new sessionid

Tags: php, session

The following code works on my desktop in chrome for setting up a session. However, on my phone in chrome it constantly gives  new sessionid upon refreshing. I've read through the other posts on her about a new sessionid every time and it seems to come down to permissions but there are no answers given. Is there something I can do to ensure this works on everyone's device, or is there a better way? I was trying to make a simple online ordering site for my restaurant.

```
<html>
<head>

 <title>Online Ordering</title>

</head>
<style>
h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
h5 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>


<?php 
session_start();

$sessionid = session_id();
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

echo "sessionNUM &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp   = $sessionid\n";
echo "<br>";        

//Connect to DB

        require_once 'configordonline.php';
        $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
        if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);


//Enter Session ID and set Order ID
    //search for session info already exsiting

    $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM HEADERS WHERE sessionid='$sessionid' AND date='$currentDate'");
    echo mysql_error();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "session info already exists";
    }
     else{


session_start();
$sessionid = session_id();

        $sql="INSERT INTO HEADERS VALUES (NULL, '$sessionid', '$currentDate', 'noneyet')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                  echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
        else {
           echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
}
        $res=$conn->query("select ORDID from HEADERS where sessionid='$sessionid'");
        list($ORDERNUM)= $res->fetch_row();
        echo "<br>";        
        echo "<br>";
        echo "ORDERNUM &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp   = $ORDERNUM\n";

        $_SESSION["OrderNum"] = $ORDERNUM;
        echo "<br>";        
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Session variables are set.";


?>

</body>
</html>
```

output on desktop:

```
sessionNUM          = 055666a122f5f77e748880c5e488c443 
session info already exists

ORDERNUM          = 77 

Session variables are set.
```

on mobile (new sessionNUM and ORDERNUM on every refresh:

```
sessionNUM          = a703f4b3492be025c7b01cda45fb3653 
New record created successfully

ORDERNUM          = 113 

Session variables are set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Per this post, I discovered that the session start should come before the html, then the rest of the php after.

[Login works on desktop but not mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570826/login-works-on-desktop-but-not-mobile)

It seems to be working fine now.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>

 <title>Online Ordering</title>

</head>
<style>
h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
h5 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>


<?php 


$sessionid = session_id();
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');

echo "sessionNUM &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp   = $sessionid\n";
echo "<br>";        

//Connect to DB

        require_once 'configordonline.php';
        $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
        if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);


//Enter Session ID and set Order ID
    //search for session info already exsiting

    $result=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM HEADERS WHERE sessionid='$sessionid' AND date='$currentDate'");
    echo mysql_error();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "session info already exists";
    }
     else{


$sessionid = session_id();

        $sql="INSERT INTO HEADERS VALUES (NULL, '$sessionid', '$currentDate', 'noneyet')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                  echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
        else {
           echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
}
        $res=$conn->query("select ORDID from HEADERS where sessionid='$sessionid'");
        list($ORDERNUM)= $res->fetch_row();
        echo "<br>";        
        echo "<br>";
        echo "ORDERNUM &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp   = $ORDERNUM\n";

        $_SESSION["OrderNum"] = $ORDERNUM;
        echo "<br>";        
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Session variables are set.";


?>
```