# autodownload script firefox PHP or JS or Any other

Tags: firefox

I have created the auto download script of images(JPG,PNG etc) and it is working fine in all browser except the firefox(latest version).

In firefox, before download start the browser is opening the popup asking open with or save file.

Kindly give me direction to save the file automatically using PHP or JS or htaccess etc in firefox.

See the URL as below
http://maples-web-services.com/autodownload/index.php

Many Thanks!!

Comment: which Firefox version you are using? I have tested with FF 27.0, there is no popup coming and download started automatically. Also house.jpg is not opening after being downloaded.

Comment: The popup is coming in my firefox. My firefor version is same as yours. May be you have checked the checkbox saying "automatically save". If this is not so then please tell me how it can possible that your firefox is not opening a browser and saved it automatically.

Comment: No I haven't checked "automatically save". Check in FF safe mode: Go to Help -> Restart with Addons disabled, then try it.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to tell you this. I googled and got the possibility for your problem.
In chrome we don't have 'open with' feature. But in Firefox we have such. So this link [Firefox issue](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file)  will gives you some information..

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I am asking to do it via PHP. I am not looking to set manually. I am trying that when any user will open the URL then download will start automatically.

Comment: I am asking for PHP script like if the mentioned URL opens in chrome then download will start automatically but in firefox, before download start the popup appears asking for mode of action "save file" or "open with". I want to do same in firefox as in chrome so that in firefox, there will no any popup will appear as in chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943/how-to-automatically-start-a-download-in-php

Answer (score 0):

It is the addons which are causing problem. Try using Safe mode in FF:

```
Go to Help -> Restart with Addons disabled
```

and then try it. If the problem is not persisting then it the addon which is causing problem. To identify the 'con' addon, check them by turning them on one by one.