# Download cropped image using php

Tags: php, download

I have the following code which displays a cropped image on the screen, but I would like this image to automatically download as well as display on screen.

The file name can be anything random.

```
$targ_w = 800;
$targ_h = 600;

$jpeg_quality = 80;

$vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']);

$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$vImg,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
```

Comment: Change the second parameter in imagejpeg() to specify a filename.
Also a simple Stackoverflow search can find your solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943/how-to-automatically-start-a-download-in-php

Comment: don't use the `@` suppression operator. it's the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalalala can't hear you".