# how to download a .txt file by clicking using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a .TXT file on my xampp server, if a user clicks on a link it should download, but instead it opens up in my browser window.

My code looks as follows:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/task/start/<?php echo $files->task_verify_file;?>"><?php echo $files->task_verify_file;?></a>
```

any one solve the problem thanks

Comment: Maybe you will find your answer here
[how-to-automatically-start-a-download-in-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943/how-to-automatically-start-a-download-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
if (file_exists ($file)) {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    readfile($file);
}
```