# Converting PHP File into pdf without page change

Tags: javascript, php, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert download a pdf file generated by PHP. The problem which I am facing is My PHP file is getting converted into PDF but it is happening in another tab. For Suppose the user Click in download button which is navigating in another page where the PHP file is getting converted into PDF and its getting closed after PDF conversion.

My hyperlink is :

```
<td><a href="b2b/electricity_invoice.php?id=<?= $v1['id'] ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
```

And Electricity Invoice file is :

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
              <script>
            $('#cmd2').click(function() {
                var options = {
                    //'width': 800,
                };
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
                pdf.addHTML($("#content2"), 0, 0, options, function() {
                    pdf.save('<?php echo 'ECTY/0'.$details['id'].'/2017-'.date("Y") ?>.pdf');
                });
            });
            </script>
```

```html
<body id="content2" onLoad="document.getElementById('cmd2').click();">
    <br><br><br>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><font size="3"><center>Electricity Bill Payment Receipt</center></font></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><center>Receipt for Payment of Bill. This Receipt is generated from {{Project Name}}</center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Receipt ID: ECTY/0<?= $details['id'].'/2017-'.date("Y") ?></td>
                <td>Date: <?= $details['date']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Customer Number: <?= $details['name']; ?> </td>
                <td>Collection Month: N/A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile No : <?= $details['cmobile']; ?></td>
                <td>Board Name: <?= getOperatorsNameById($details['opId']); ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount : <?= $details['amount']; ?></td>
                <td>Status: <?= $details['status']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p> <center>For and on Behalf of {{Project Name}}</center> </p>
           <button class="btn btn-info" id="cmd2" onclick="setTimeout(function(){var ww = window.open(window.location, '_self'); ww.close(); }, 500);">Download Token</button>
            
    </body>
```

Comment: remove `target="_blank"` if you don't want it to open in new tab

Comment: But if I won't use then it will close my project too.

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943/how-to-automatically-start-a-download-in-php

Comment: Then you probably should remove `ww.close();` part

Comment: please upvote as well if its helpfull to you.. @NikitaAgrawal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use target="_blank" if you don't want to open in new tab.