# How to Download Automatically an xml format file direct from my computer or in download folder after converted into CSV TO XML

Tags: php, xml, csv

Need help sir, I want to automatically download an XML format files from my computer or download folder..  Now its only saving on my working directory the xml converted file, Is that possible Automatically Download save after converted into XML?

```
<?php
// Map CSV file to array
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
// Process Data if need be
foreach($data AS $key => $val)
{
    // Processing here
}
 //Creates XML string and XML document using the DOM 
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
//Add root node
$root = $xml->createElement('root');
$xml->appendChild($root);
// Add child nodes
foreach($data AS $key => $val) 
{   
    $entry = $xml->createElement('entry');
    $root->appendChild($entry);

    foreach($val AS $field_name => $field_value) 
    {   
        $field_name = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $field_name); // preg_replace has the allowed characters
        $name = $entry->appendChild($xml->createElement($field_name)); 
        $name->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection($field_value)); 
    }
}
// Set the formatOutput attribute of xml to true
$xml->formatOutput = true; 
// Output to screen
//header('Content-Type: text/xml');
//echo $xml->saveXML();
// Save as file
$xml->save('xml-import.xml'); // save as file
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Automatically Start a Download in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943/how-to-automatically-start-a-download-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

DomDocument has a `saveXML` method which returns a string that you can pass to the browser.
http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savexml.php

```
$str_xml = $xml->saveXML();
echo $str_xml;
```

Comment: sir. I want it automatically download the converted csv files.  Only Save the xml files on my working directory. I want also automatically download just like when you download movies or other stuff in the internet directly into your download folder.  sorry to bother you